# It is possible to add non-latin characters in css content pseudo-element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

It is possible to add non-latin characters in css "content" pseudo-element?

I have code like this:

```
&::after{
             content:"(לחץ לחיוג)";
             color: #00b1eb;
             text-decoration: underline;
             font-family: "Open Sans", "Narkis Block M F" !important;
             font-size: 32px;
           }
```

and on the browser I got this Gibberish:

[image]

if the string that in content: is English everything is ok:

[image]

there is a way to add Hebrew or not English characters to a content pseudo element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print non-latin symbols using unicode sequences like in this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNjgGz)
e.g.

```
body::before {
  content:"(\05DC\05D7\05E5 \05DC\05D7\05D9\05D5\05D2)";
}
```

(I used [this tool](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) to make the conversion of your characters into UTF-8 units)